# Remove 0's from a decimal number

Tags: objective-c, math

I have been looking for some time for a method that will remove the 0's after a decimal place but keeps the numbers after the 0's.

I am working with a timestamp that needs to end up a double between 0-1 as a priority level for displaying articles. I first divided 1 by the timestamp (1539353737) which results in 0.000000000649623 and I would like the final double left with to be 0.649623 how would I go about doing that. Its not as easy as just removing any 0 as the final number could have an important 0 in it for example: 0.640980

Edit: The end goal is to calculate a priority level to display articles meaning that the higher the timestamp the greater the value should be between 0 and 1 to display.

Edit 2: The reason I cannot order by timestamp as I need a universal variable that can be used to order the articles. There is other arrays which are being sorted into having a 'priority level' so need to keep the same

Thanks,

Comment: Can you explain why you're dividing by that number? Also... what are you actually trying to do? Why do you want a number between 0 and 1?

Comment: Hmm... ok... I see where the number came from now... still not quite sure what you're trying to do though? Why do you need a number between 0 and 1? What does that mean for your program? What will you do with it?

Comment: From your edit... are more recent articles more important? Or are older articles more important? Either way... can you not just use the timestamp to sort them?

Comment: This is very much an XY Problem... https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you are doing maths with the timestamp that is unnecessary?

From your question...

> The end goal is to calculate a priority level to display articles meaning that the higher the timestamp the greater the value should be between 0 and 1 to display.

Can you not just sort the articles by the `date` or `timestamp` of the article?

With a descending (or ascending) sort you can arrange the articles so that the most recent articles or at the top (or bottom) of the list.

There is no maths required to do this. The timestamp is already a number that can be sorted. Just sort on the date (or timestamp).

Comment: The reason I cannot order by timestamp as I need a universal variable that can be used to order the articles. There is other arrays which are being sorted into having a 'priority level' so need to keep the same.

Comment: OK... what determines the other items' priorities? Why is this information not in the original question? What do you want to be first? Today's articles? What priority do they need to make sure they're first? Doing `1/timestamp` will make today's articles have a lower priority. Trimming zeroes is useless as it makes `0.06` the same as `0.006`. Etc...

Comment: @LouisFerraiolo put all of this information into your original question.

Comment: it is not as simple as 1/timestamp as it also involves a babys dob timestamp which is in the equation. Basically any article posted after the babys dob is more important.

Comment: @LouisFerraiolo I know it isn't as simple as `1/timestamp` I mentioned it because you put it in your question. My point was that using `1/timestamp` will not work.

Comment: @LouisFerraiolo So you have articles with a date and a baby with a date (of birth). So far these are all sortable using date. Is there anything else that has a priority? If not then it falls back to the same thing... sort by date.